# Why does curl need to be set this way to allow using fiddler and the rest doesn't?

Tags: php, curl, netbeans, fiddler

I tried using curl with  netbean and my traffic do not show up on fiddler.

I look things up and I saw

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigurePHPcURL

It says I have to set proxy to

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');

I sort of understand.

But my visual studio, my firefox, and everything doesn't have to set proxy.

Why does my netbean curl requires me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configure Browsers for Fiddler > Manual Configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureBrowsers#manual-configuration):

> To manually configure any browser to send traffic to Fiddler, set the
>   browser to connect to a proxy server. This setting is usually in the
>   Options or Preferences menu. Use these settings:
>
> Address: 127.0.0.1 Port: 8888

So NetBeans requires the same settings for capturing cURL traffic.

Comment: That is the question. The other browser are able to connect through fiddler without

Comment: [From here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/capture-messages-on-a-rest-api-endpoint#M06yTqoeJEWiEybKsva0hA):
"Fiddler is a proxy; it captures everything that's sent to it. By default, it registers as the system proxy for your local PC, so that applications (like browsers, Office, etC) that use the system proxy will automatically send their traffic to Fiddler when Fiddler is "attached." Some clients (e.g. Opera, CURL, Java, etc) require manual configuration to set their traffic to proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888".

Comment: If you want to know exactly which way Fiddler developers use to get traffic without a proxy, I think it's better to ask them on their forum.